# Is it possible to use Equivalent Exchange to convert Cobblestone to Wood in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I'm working on setting up an 'everything' factory in minecraft using equivalent exchange and buildcraft. However, I would like the sole source material to be cobblestone, and it seems there's no way to convert non-organic items into organic, so it doesn't seem I can convert cobble to wood.

Is there a way to do this with EE or not?

Comment: As soon as I saw `"Equivalent Exchange"` in the question title I started looking for a [tag:fullmetal-alchemist] tag.

Comment: Wait, couldn't you use an Energy Condenser? Or am I mixing my mods up?

Comment: I think so, but I've not actually tried EE6 yet, and the energy condenser didn't work like that in EE5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note**

This method doesn't work in EEv6+ as the recipes were all removed.

**End note**

After 45 mins of tracing recipes, I settled on a roughly 23 step conversion process that can convert cobble into wood.

Basically it goes like this (I won't have access to the computer with the details again until later):

```
1) Cobble
2) Dirt
3) Sand
4) Glass
5) Ice
6) Lapis
7) *lots of changing dyes*
8) Cactus green
9) Saplings
10) Wood
```

From experimenting with that it seems that you should be able to navigate from cobble to any other item on the EE crafting tree by using dyes as a go-between. =)

**edit**

After further perusing recipes, here's the shortest version so far:

```
1) Cobble
2) Dirt
3) Sand
4) Glass
5) Ice
6) Lapis
7) *lots of changing dyes*
8) Cocoa beans
9) Wood
```

Comment: Ingenious! I spent a long time yesterday trying to make the conversion, but failed. The ice to lapis to other dye is the key for sure. I think I found a [shorter way](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42334/3389) than what you're suggesting here, though.

Comment: Looking at the dye recipes more it seems that I could have changed the dyes just one more time to get cocoa beans, and done 6x cocoa beans => 9 wood. I think the exchange rate is the same though. So I see your short recipe and raise you an even shorter one, lol.

Answer (score 7):

Just use an energy condenser, and it will turn quite literally anything put into it into whatever is in the top left slot, including wood.

Comment: Or just put the energy into a Klein Star and then lock your tablet to a fuel.

Answer (score -2):

No. [You can see a list of wood-related recipes here, on the equivalent wiki.](http://equivalentexchange.wikispaces.com/Plants+and+Wood) Nothing about wood from cobblestone.